# htmlspecialchars is not allowing line breaks?

Tags: php

I have the following apprear exactly like this in a mysql field,

```
 Hello there
 world
```

When i format the above using this code:

```
 echo htmlspecialchars($thestring)
```

It outputs this,

```
 Hello there<br/><br/>world
```

How can i get it to do line breaks?

I would like to keep using htmlspecialchars to help with the other html chars.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` will not convert literal line breaks into anything.

Comment: Are you by chance doing `htmlspecialchars(nl2br($text))`?

Comment: yeah after you asked i check code, and it was nl2br'ed further up the chain.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `nl2br` to get the line breaks converted to html:

```
nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text))
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

```html
<![CDATA[<br/>]]>
```

this did the trick for me

Comment: I don't understand how or where to use your answer in the PHP code, would you explain, please? Click `Edit` under your answer and add the explanation, that will increase the chances to get upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you get `<br>` tags in a string after `htmlspecialchars()` it means that you have exactly `<br>` tags in your string (NOT `\n` line breaks) because `htmlspecialchars()` doesn't convert `\n` to `<br>`.

If so, you have to make a double transformation from `<br>` to `\n` and back:

**Step 1.** Transform `<br>` to `\n`

**Step 2.** Run `htmlspecialchars()`

**Step 3.** Transform `\n` to `<br>`

Example:

```php
    <?php
        echo
            str_replace(  // Step 3
                "\n",
                "<br />",
                htmlspecialchars(  // Step 2
                    str_replace(  // Step 1
                        array("<br />", "<br/>", "<br>"), // make sure that you have your version of <br> tag here
                        "\n", 
                        $text
                    ),
                    ENT_QUOTES,
                    'UTF-8'
                )
            );
    ?>
```