# dynamically add backslash to end of string line

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have code that gets some text from database and inserts it inside `javascript var`. This is the code:

```
<script>
var = <?php echo $var ?>
</script>
```

When the page is loaded, `var` looks like this:

```
<script>
var = "This is first line
This is second
This is third..."
</script>
```

Is there a way to dynamically add a backslash after each line?

**EDIT :**

I am using `PHP` to echo the text and I want to manipulate it inside `javascript`

Comment: Please edit your question and be more specific if you want to manipulate the string when still in PHP or when in Javascript.

Comment: Are you just echoing the value in PHP? Check out json_encode()

Comment: I think it would be easier to make the transform in PHP. As far as I know, javascript does not like "literal" line breaks. See here : http://www.willmaster.com/blog/javascript/strings-line-breaks.php

Comment: Can you please provide sample code for `PHP` transform?

Comment: Literal line breaks as @Bonatoc mentioned; in Javascript have to be concatenated otherwise it will throw an ILLEGAL identifier error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the variable into new lines with whatever delimiter you like:

```
<?php
$var = "This is line 1|##|This is line 2|##|This is line 3";
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var lines = "<?=$var?>";
var res = lines.split("|##|");

res.forEach(function(entry) {
    alert(entry + "\\");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code in `PHP` for that?

Comment: What is the final use of the string? Just curious.

Comment: Up to his discretion really, I provided a decent starting point for him to learn the rest through other avenues :) It's worth noting that my original answer recommended the use of \r\n whilst in PHP, this obviously creates the literal line breaks in javascript, so I just went the delimiter route.

Comment: I have simple code snippets application that retrieves code from database and puts it inside ACE editor. I was experimenting a bit and made my own way to solve the problem. I will post how I did it. Thanks.

Comment: I've used ACE before, all you need to use is `htmlentities($codeforACE)`;

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but not really viable if OP is trying to output a string that is being pulled from somewhere else. I've posted a more straightforward solution below.

Answer (score 2):

How you escape something depends on the context you use it in.

If you don't want line breaks to be included literally in the HTML output, you have to encode them as '\n'. But if a newline character is preceded by a slash in the output, e.g.:

```
\<newline>
```

then you have to escape the backslash too. Otherwise, escaping the newline only will actually just escape the backslash:

```
\\<newline>
```

So to backslash a newline, you must backslash the backslashes first and then backslash the newlines:

```
\\\<newline>
```

We also have to watch out for XSS (cross-site scripting) attempts. If someone inserts a `</script>` into your string, then they could prematurely end your script block (even though it's in a JS quote!) and change the behavior of your page. To prevent this, we backslash the forward slash so that it doesn't read as a literal `</script>` to the HTML parser. (See below.)

The three PHP functions that are most useful for this sort of thing are `addslashes`, `htmlspecialchars` and `str_replace`.

To escape for a JS string (and escape the newline characters), you can use the following function:

```php
<?php
function escapeForJSString($var) {
    return str_replace(
        "/" // escape forward slash to help prevent XSS
        , "\\/"
        , str_replace(
            "\n" // escape newline
            , "\\n"
            , addslashes($var) // escape single quotes, double quotes, backslash, and null byte
        )
    );
}
?>
```

In your code:

```
<?php
$var = "You can find the file at C:\\Program Files\\Cool Program\\Preferences.txt > colorScheme
    if you want to change it.</script>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lines = "<?= escapeForJSString($var) ?>";
    alert(lines);
</script>
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lines = "You can find the file at C:\\Program Files\\Cool Program\\Preferences.txt > colorScheme\n  if you want to change it.<\/script>";
alert(lines);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

A couple notes:

- You have to have a variable *name*, not just `var`.
- Put quotes around strings.
- You can either use `<?php echo $var ?>` or `<?= $var ?>` ([`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) must be enabled in your php.ini file if you're using a version of prior to PHP 5.4).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. (Note that if you're using 5.4.0+, then `<?= ?>` is always enabled, unlike `<? ?>`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121880/htmlspecialchars-is-not-allowing-line-breaks